# Need Single Firebase Analytics for Android SDK and Android Application in android

Tags: android, sdk, firebase-analytics, android-studio-3.5

I have developed a SDK and integrated Firebase analytics in it. And also i have an android application integrated with another firebase analytics. Now I want to integrate this SDK in android application and want to track both SDK and Application's analytics with single firebase account. Is there any solution to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Ok.

You can multiple firebase apps in one application. One for the sdk and one for the app.

First, you create 2 separate apps first on the firebase project. Then, the trick here is you create multiple FirebaseOption and init the FirebaseApp with as much options as you want.

```
  FirebaseOptions options1 =
      new FirebaseOptions.Builder(firebaseOptions)
          .setProjectId("mock-project-id-1")
          .build();
  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options1, "testVerifyIdTokenWithExplicitProjectId");

    FirebaseOptions options2 =
      new FirebaseOptions.Builder(firebaseOptions)
          .setProjectId("mock-project-id-2")
          .build();
  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options2, "testVerifyIdTokenWithExplicitProjectId");
```

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-[an-android-app.html](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html)

Comment: Do i need to implement this in SDK or in app? And what if I integrate this SDK in another app? Do i need to create another app in firebase?

Comment: For the 1st question: you will make it in 2 places. Init option 1 in the sdk and option 2 in the integrated app.

For the second question: I guess you making some vendor sdk, arent you ? If that the situation is you just want to track the current using of the sdk regardless which app has integrated it, then no need. Just keep the same app Id for the tracker. The integrated app may be on another project or even on a another account

Comment: If i use this approach I don't want to place google-services.json file in my project.Do I?

Comment: No, it's no need. Since the file content will be read and put in value xml in the compiled time as I remember.

Comment: @baasu dont forget to check the FirebaseOptions in docs to not missing the builder params. Cheers.